# How do i simulate object-fit: fill with fluent-ffmpeg nodejs

Tags: css, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, object-fit

`ffmpeg(input) .output(output) .outputOptions("-vf",`scale=w=${1920}:h=${1080}`) .outputOptions("-c:a", "copy") .on("end", () => { console.log("Video conversion completed"); }) .on("error", error => { console.error("Video conversion failed:", error); }) .on("progress", function(f) { console.log("...frames ", f.frames); }) .run()`
code behave more like object-fit: contain than fill

Comment: Add `-report` option and rerun. Share report.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.